# Error running CXF REST web service on Apache Tomee

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, cxf, apache-tomee

I'm trying to build a RESTful web service using the "org.apache.cxf.archetype:cxf-jaxrs-service" maven archetype. When I deploy it on Apache Tomee I get the following error:

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'services': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
>   ...
>   ...
>   Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:219)
>   ...
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl to org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager*

My guess is I'm missing some configuration but I thought the archetype would 'just work'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

this error means you have a conflict between cxf in the webapp (WEB-INF/lib) and tomee. You either have to configure the classloading to do that or (recommanded and expected by EE) just remove CXF from the webapp since it is in tomee and tomee does the job for you.

Side note: you will also likely need to clean up the web.xml since tomee will handle the deployment without the need to register a servlet.